# 9patch is stretching areas I didn't mark

Tags: android, nine-patch

I've created a 9patch for a background area and it seems to be stretching areas I didn't mark to be stretched. I have it so that vertically it should stretch 1 pixel from the middle, but it's still stretching the top and bottom borders. Here's my 9patch, placed in the `drawable` folder:

[image: 9patch]

And here's the resulting image when placed as the `background` attribute for a layout:

[image: screenshot]

Why is it stretching the top and bottom borders? I want these to stay 2 pixels on the top and 4 pixels on the bottom, but its stretching.

You can download the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohTDC.png) if you want to try this out. Rename it so it has a .9.png extension, place it as the `background` in a `View` about 100dp tall, take a screenshot, then zoom in and you can see what I'm seeing.

Comment: is it resulting okay in draw9patch editor? and is the file has .9.png extension with it?

Comment: [Android How to use 9 patch png](http://adilsoomro.blogspot.com/2012/11/android-how-to-use-9-patch-png.html)

Comment: @AdilSoomro Yes it has a .9.png extension. It's hard to tell in the preview if it's scaling correctly because the image is so small and the largest I can zoom them is 6x.

Comment: @AdilSoomro I included the 9patch at the end of my question if you want to try it out on your end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's being scaled. If you place it in `res/drawable`, it's going to scale up 1.5x on HDPI devices, and 2x on XHDPI devices (drawables there are assumed to be MDPI). You can either place it in `res/drawable-nodpi` to keep it from scaling, or make larger versions if desired and place them in `res/drawable-hdpi`/`res/drawable-xhdpi` folders.

Comment: Dude, you just changed my life. Had no idea there was a `drawable-nodpi` option. That works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: Always happy to change lives! For better or worse. :P