# Incorrect stretching of simple 9-patch image to get 1px border on high-res devices

Tags: android, border, nine-patch

I want to get a simple 1px border with white background as 9-patch for a view in android application. It works fine on the Samsung Galaxy Tab 730, but to my suprise, the result on Samsung Nexus 10 is completely different:

Desired result (1px blue border and white background): [image: Info Window with 9-patch background correctly displayed].

Actual result (1px blue border and light blue background): [image: Info Window with 9-patch background and blue background (incorrectly stretched)]

The used 9-patch is very simple: [image: used 9-patch image], enlarged: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions I found worked for me:

- *Dirty hack:* Replacing the image with the following slightly bigger image (that is not affected by rescaling on the larger screen device, but might be affected on even larger displays): [image: 9-patch 1px border with 3x3px white], enlarged [image]
- *Correct solution:* Moving the 9-patch image to the folder `res/drawable-nodpi` (see [9patch is stretching areas I didn't mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298987/9patch-is-stretching-areas-i-didnt-mark)) to prevent it from being rescaled on any devices.